# Windows 7 Stuck on "Applying Software Installation policy" for extended period of time

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, windows-server-2012

I have four Windows 7 clients that are connecting to a Server 2012 domain controller EC2 isntance. There was also a file server (also Server 2012), but I decided to merge the two together because the Amazon advising tool said we were wasting money with our setup. So, I moved the EBS volumes to the domain controller and they're all working fine, but I had to recreate the software installation policy to point to the new shares.

I simply removed and re-added the same software with the same settings except for the file path. Now, the clients are constantly spending time when booting up in "Applying Software Installation policy" mode. It takes a good 20-30 minutes to get past that step. Before the move it was taking 10 seconds or so (when the software is installed).

I tested a PC by uninstalling all of the managed software and then disjointing and rejoining to the domain. There was no effect...

How can I fix this? Also, user profiles (even recreated ones) seem to be behaving very slowly on logins or logouts...

Comment: Re-creating the software installation policy should cause the assigned software to be removed and reinstalled on the client machines. Keep in mind that installing assigned software *over the internet* will take a very long time, and the exact amount of time is very difficult to predict accurately without testing in a specific environment.

Comment: It takes about 15 minutes to do a full installation of everything over the VPN connection, however it seems to be attempting continuously redo it. When I removed the previous deployment settings I did opt to leave the software installed on the machines, not sure if that will cause issues?

Comment: Very likely. I have always set assigned software to be removed if the GPO no longer applies, so I have no personal experience in the territory that you're describing, but I think you are on to something. Have you tried removing the assigned software manually on one of the computers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be running [Microsoft SysInternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) in boot logging mode to see where the delays are (use the **Duration** column).

Also, anything in the System event log?  Plus, check the file system for log files (msi*.log and appmgmt.log).

Finally, check the registry of one of the clients.  I can't remember the location, but the installed MSIs hold on to their installation source UNC.  There's a chance that the Windows Installer is trying to locate the un-install code from the original UNC.  Process monitor should also show this.  If not, do a wireshark trace.

Comment: I finally had a chance to continue on this. The ProcMon log has a couple of offenders: SVCHOST > NotifyChangeDirectory > ~800 seconds; SEARCHINDEXER > ~480 seconds. Googling hasn't yielded useful results.

Comment: I forgot to get the SEARCHINDEXER operation, but the details say: FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL.

Comment: I got rid of the SEARCHINDEXER by disabling Windows Search completely, but the SVCHOST remains and it's not getting up into the 80 minute range...

Comment: it's NOW*** getting...